# Podbc + Pyinstaller issue pyodbc.InterfaceError IM002

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, pyodbc

I know there was something similar here, but despite following advice from previous threads I am still having the same issue.
I run this code in my Pycharm and it works well.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas
import os
import sys

try:
    currdir = os.path.abspath(__file__)
except NameError:  
     import sys
currdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
DBfile = os.path.join(currdir, 'UNION.accdb')
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%s;' %DBfile)
sql = "Select * FROM topivot"
df = pandas.read_sql(sql,cnxn)

print(df)
```

Then I run the command `pyinstaller --onefile pydbb.py` and it gives me the `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` error. So I create the .spec file by `pyi-Makespec --onefile pydbb.py` and then run `pyinstaller --onefile pyddb.spec`.

The .spec file looks like this

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

block_cipher = None 


a = Analysis(['pyddb2.py'],
         pathex= 
['C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      [],
      name='pyddb2',
      debug=False,
      bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=True )
```

This successfully creates the file (365MB! for some reason), but it gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "pyddb2.py", line 12, in <module> 
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] 
Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) 
(SQLDriverConnect)') [10948] Failed to execute script pyddb2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Add `print(pyodbc.drivers())` to the beginning of your script. Build the .exe and run it. Does 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)' appear in the list of available drivers?

Comment: Okay, Pycharm lists the `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)' driver` but EXE shows `'SQL Server', 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server', 'PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)', 'PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)', 'Amazon Redshift (x64 I', 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0', 'SQL Server Native Client RDA 11.0']` and the same IM002 error.

Comment: Ìs it possible that it lists drivers in ODBC Data Source Administration (64-bit)? However in "User DSN" is the MS Access Database Driver. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you fix this issue?